# Override function in custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin with this action:

```
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', array( $this, 'pre_save_review' ), 10, 2 );
```

I've written a plugin to do some tweaking to my site here and there. Mostly REST API customizations.

I'd like to override, subvert, ignore, remove, that filter. Right now I've got it "working" by just `return`ing on the first line of the `pre_save_review` function.

I tried:

```
remove_action( 'pre_comment_approved', 'pre_save_review');
```

... but I wonder if there's some namespacing issue. I don't know a lot about PHP so I don't know how to refer to classes in other files/plugins, which I imagine is the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see other answers giving details about this however the reason you can't just remove the action is because you registered it with an object and to unregister it you need that SAME object. The object that is `$this` when adding the action needs to also be used when you remove it. When you add actions inside objects like this you need to keep the registration object around in case you need it later. This is one of the reasons the singleton pattern is poplar in WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all filters with a wordpress function "remove_all_filters"

```
remove_all_filters('pre_comment_approved');
```

This also has a second parameter to pass the priority number, since this one is added with priority 10 it would be this:

```
remove_all_filters('pre_comment_approved', 10);
```

Reference [remove_all_filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_filters)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `remove_filter` function for this.

See the Example in the documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

> If a filter has been added from within a class, for example by a
>   plugin, removing it will require accessing the class variable.

```
global $my_class;
remove_filter( 'the_content', array($my_class, 'class_filter_function') );
```

So maybe give the following a try;

```
global $this;
remove_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', array( $this, 'pre_save_review' ) );
```